# T-SQL Left Join using "or" operator

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, left-join

I have the following query where I would like to pull in either or both on a match. There can be more than one ID or HIC for a member. So if the `member ID = member ID` then pull the max (loaddate) for the most current HIC Likewise if `HIC = HIC` pull in the member ID with the max (loaddate). I want to include the left join in case a match isn't found for either scenario.

Code:

```
 SELECT 
    CH1.*
    ,AVM.MBR_ID
    ,AVM.HIC
    ,AVM.MBR_LST_NM
    ,AVM.MBR_FST_NM
    ,CAST(AVM.MBR_BIRTH_DT AS DATE) AS 'MBR_BIRTH_DT'
    ,AVM.LOADDATE
FROM 
    #CHECK1 CH1
LEFT JOIN 
    AVRIL.DBO.VW_MBR AVM ON (CH1.HICN = AVM.HIC OR CH1.MEMBER_ID = AVM.MBR_ID)
WHERE 
    CH1.HEALTH_PLAN = 'AVRIL' 
    AND AVM.LOADDATE=(SELECT MAX(LOADDATE) FROM AVRIL.DBO.VW_MBR)
```

Thanks, 
Michael

Comment: This does not pull the correct results. It omits several records from the original #check1 table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use a field from the `VW_MBR` table in the `where` clause, it effectively turns the `left join` into an `inner join`. Put the condition in the join:

```
...
FROM #CHECK1 CH1
    LEFT JOIN AVRIL.DBO.VW_MBR AVM ON (CH1.HICN = AVM.HIC OR CH1.MEMBER_ID = AVM.MBR_ID)
      AND AVM.LOADDATE=(SELECT MAX(LOADDATE) FROM AVRIL.DBO.VW_MBR)
WHERE CH1.HEALTH_PLAN = 'AVRIL'
```

Comment: easy enough, I've been beating myself in the head over this for the last couple hours. Thanks!!

Comment: @Michael - Though the condition really belongs in the `ON` clause for clarity, an alternative is to rewrite the `WHERE` clause to allow a null: `WHERE .. AND ( AVM.LOADDATE IS NULL OR AVM.LOADDATE = ( SELECT ... ) )`. That way unmatched rows will still be included.

Comment: @Michael If that is the answer then you should give it the Check

Comment: Thanks for the help, now I identified something else I should have included. So the max(loaddate) could be different between the HIC and Member ID. So what will happen if the CH1.HICN = AVM.HIC has a max date of 4/23/2015 and CH1.MEMBER_ID = AVM.MBR_ID has a max date of 4/24/2015 this won't pull, right? I am receiving all the results from the left join, but without some of the matches that can be attributed to the above scenario.

Comment: It may be overkill, but I ended just sending that data into another temp table, then running this code and it gave me the desired result. SELECT CH2.*

INTO #CHECK3
 FROM #CHECK2 CH2,
  (SELECT MAX(LOADDATE) AS MAX_LOADDATE, [ENG ID]
   FROM #CHECK2
  GROUP BY [ENG ID]) MAXLD 
 WHERE MAXLD.[ENG ID] = CH2.[ENG ID]
  AND MAXLD.MAX_LOADDATE = CH2.LOADDATE

Answer (score 0):

Here may be an alternative to the first proposed answer, I'm using a custom query as jointure in order to optimize it (I use only the max load dates instead of trying the jointure on every rows of the table).

```
SELECT CH1.*
    ,MAVM.MBR_ID
    ,MAVM.HIC
    ,MAVM.MAX_LOADDATE
FROM #CHECK1 CH1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT AVM.HIC
               ,AVM.MBR_ID
               MAX(AVM.LOADDATE) AS [MAX_LOADDATE]
           FROM AVRIL.DBO.VW_MBR AVM
           GROUP BY AVM.HIC, AVM.MBR_ID) MAVM (MAVM.HIC = CH1.HICN
                                                  OR MAVM.MBR_ID = CH1.MEMBER_ID)
WHERE CH1.HEALTH_PLAN = 'AVRIL'
```

I simplified the query to focus on the changes in comparison with the other proposed query. You can still add an `INNER JOIN` clause to `AVRIL.DBO.VM_MBR` in order to get additional columns:

```
...
LEFT JOIN (...) MAVM ...
INNER JOIN AVRIL.DBO.VW_MBR AVM2 ON AVM2.HIC = MAVM.HIC
                                   AND AVM2.MBR_ID = MAVM.MBR_ID
                                   AND AVM2.LOADDATE = MAVM.MAX_LOADDATE
...
```

So you can use `AVM2.xxx` for the columns you want to use.

Hope this will help